# When building a springboot app it fails with "No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, encryption, spring-cloud

I'm running a springboot application it's got secret keys and access keys that are encrypted using the config server. The decryption works fine at runtime, however when building the application there are unit tests that are running and they fail because of failed decryption (when i remove cypher and put plain text keys this works fine). Is it possible to access the config server and decrypt the keys at build time?